# What's the difference between oyogemasu and oyogu koto ga dekimasu?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I know they both mean "I can swim". But when using the potential form of a verb is there nuanced difference between -emasu/raremasu and koto ga dekimasu or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

Same and interchangeable.

- この植物は食べられる＝この植物は食べることが出来る
- 私は泳げる＝私は泳ぐことができる
- 富士山は東京から見れる＝富士山は東京から見ることが出来る。
- 水は水素と酸素から作れる＝水は水素と酸素から作ることが出来る。
- この服は家で洗える＝この服は家で洗う事が出来る。
- 時間があるので今話せる＝時間があるので今話す事が出来る。

Would like to know if there is an example which cannot be interchangeable.

Comment: Not interchangeable when the 可能形動詞 does not normally exist (verbs like 分かる　入る).

Comment: @virmajor, if there is no case of 可能形 such as with 分かる, I believe there would be no point in considering ことができる form. If there is a form of 可能形 for a verb, then ことができる should be the interchangeable form.

Comment: この「見れる」「出れる」「来れる」などの言い方は，話し言葉としては昭和初期から一部で用いられており，第二次世界大戦後は更に一般化し，最近では，話し言葉だけでなく書き言葉としても用いられるようになった。(http://www.kyoiku-shuppan.co.jp/textbook/shou/kokugo/document/ducu3/104.html)

Answer (score 1):

Almost no difference.

One is more "modular" (& easier for learners) :

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1115782476
>
> 会話ではあまり使わないのに、なぜ外国人の日本語学習者に「ことができる」を先に教えるかというと、 それは活用の形がやさしくて、すぐに使えるようになるからです。
>
> どの動詞も、辞書形さえわかれば、「ことができる」はすぐに使えます。 それでじゅうぶん｢可能」の意味が通じます。

[Would like to know if there is an example which cannot be interchangeable.]

This page (see link above) says that some passive forms are impossible with the
V~える form.

> （例・親の愛情を知らない子どもは、大人になっても愛されることができない。・・・ 愛されられない、とは言えません）

Great point !